# Error de instalacion de un proyecto de vue desde github

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify

Buenas tardes me podrian ayudar a solucionar este error de instalacion de un proyecto vue,vuetify que clone de github

a la hora de ejecutar el comando de npm install o el comando de npm run serve me sale este error o culaquier otro comando no me deja hacer nada siempre sale lo mismo

intente con npm update ,
npm run watch,
npm run dev,
npm run start
npm outdated
npm install npm@latest -g npm run build

````
```
C:\Python27\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\juan.zapata\Downloads\dayspan-vuetify-master\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juan.zapata\Downloads\dayspan-vuetify-master\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\juan.zapata\Downloads\dayspan-vuetify-master\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\juan.zapata\\Downloads\\dayspan-vuetify-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\juan.zapata\Downloads\dayspan-vuetify-master\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\juan.zapata\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-07T17_51_39_110Z-debug.log
```
````

Comment: Y el error es...?

Answer (score 0):

Siempre hay que buscar primero aquí mismo si ya existe la pregunta, por ejemplo aqui esta el mismo error tuyo.

Verifica si la solución que dieron ahi, te logra ayudar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372618/npm-cant-find-python-executable-python-you-can-set-the-python-env-variabl